# Convert a JSON parsed array containing dates to array type date Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this array:

```
var BigWordsDates = JSON.parse('<?php echo addslashes($Array_OfDates_to_json) ?>');
```

and it shows up like this (FireBug DOM):

```
BigWordsDates   Object { #Tahrir=[36], #Egypt=[24], #Morsy=[16], more...}   
#AdminCourt ["2012-10-02","2012-10-02","2012-10-09", 2 more...]
```

I would like to change it to an array of dates with a format like that: 2012-FEB-06. I would appreciate it if someone can tell how to convert that array to a CSV file.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i tried using the DateObject and some how convert it but gave me NAN.it was Date.Parse i think and i sent it the whole array.

Comment: also i googled and found this too: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/

but couldnt apply it to my code.

Comment: do i have to download Date.js to use it ? or this problem can be solved with another method ?!

Comment: So do you want to convert the date strings into date objects, or into a different format? Where does a CSV file come into it?

Comment: well the purpose of all this is that i want to draw an area chart using D3, and i thought converting the JSON parse array that i have to date object and then convert it to a CSV file to apply it on one of the examples i have.

However Right now before encoding the array i changed the format like this 2012-FEB-06 from PHP. so right now how can i change array Given above to a CSV file.

I noticed that Some managed to use charts without CSV they entered data like this:
{xCoordinate: "Legend String 1", magnitude: 54, link: "http://www.if4it.com"}];

P.S i am kinda new to D3 and JSON

Answer (score 1):

1, you have to declare a JSON for months.

```
var month = {
  '1': 'JAN',
  '2': 'FEB',

  etc.
}
```

2, parse your JSON.

```
var output = [];

for(var k in BigWordsDates['#AdminCourt']) {
    var obj = BigWordsDates['#AdminCourt'][k]; // es. '"2012-10-02"'
    var array = obj.split('-'); // == array['2012', '10', '02']

    var new_value = array[0] + '-' + month[array[1]] + '-' + array[2];

    // add the element to new array
    output.push(new_value);
}
```

Try!
Use try-catch instruction for debug the code.

This method is effective only if your JSON not change.